# What does "people reached" signify and how is it calculated?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, people-reached

I was going through the *new profiles* of top users, one of which was [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), who has reached out to 100+ million people with his posts.

A quick Google search throws up [the following article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/01/IDC-software-developers), which suggests there are only an estimated 18.5 million developers worldwide. At 111.7m people reached, the number would also mean that he has successfully reached out to a total of 1.6% of the world population, just by his posts on Stack Overflow (assuming 7bn as world population), which is hard to believe.

So what does that *people reached* metric signify?

And how is it calculated, is it a view count of all your posts, or view counts of posts plus view count of questions marked as duplicate of your posts, or is that view counts of your plus dup post factoring in the upvotes? Does it get normalized (same person viewing multiple posts of yours)?

Comment: It is explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

Comment: Maybe it would be a bit more accurate to save helped a person 111.7 m times?  I personally have been helped by more than one of his posts.  And even some posts more than once.

Comment: It's not exactly the most scientifically correct metric: just because someone viewed a post where you have a highly voted answer doesn't mean they found it helpful or even saw it. I'd take it for its amusement value and a general ballpark of your relative input in the developer community. *Very* general ballpark.

Comment: Plus, reflecting on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here 
Why would the answers have to have a score greater than 0 when questions merely need not to be deleted. I've seen new users with only down voted questions have their 'people reached' meter be the sum of their questions' views...

Comment: Since this is no longer visible in the profile after the summer 2021 profile page overhaul, should this question be closed now?

Comment: Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts
(based on page views of your questions and questions where you wrote highly-ranked answers)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The people reached statistic is a rough guesstimate of how many views all your posts have. A single view is considered to be equivalent with a single user.

There is however one slight problem with the calculation of that number. The view count is only stored for a question, not for each answer. So you can only be 100% sure a question is viewed. For questions with multiple answers you are at a loss. Also note that only the total viewcount up to this date is stored. The viewcount history isn't stored in SEDE, and AFAIK not even in the production schema.

Hence the trickery in a query using data that was already available since 2008 to also give some people reached credits to answers, as explained in [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) over on MSE.

From that post this is the formula:

- **Questions**

  - Non-deleted only
- **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:

  - Non-deleted AND
  - Score > 0 AND
  - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:

    - In the top 3 answers OR
    - Is the Accepted Answer OR
    - Score at least 5 OR
    - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

Specially if you have an answer that is around a score of 5 on a highly viewed question will result in big jumps in that number with single up- or down vote.

If you want to play a bit with that formula use the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1?UserId=811) or the improved one offered by Martin Smith: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/756276/people-reached?UserId=149428

Comment: It looks likes the metric may have changed since this post.  Running the included query against my user ID gives ~800k but impact listed on my profile is ~125k.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Hmm, strange, for my account it is pretty spot on. Keep in mind that just passing a threshold on one of the q/a pairs you answered can make a huge difference, although I don't see anything so quickly in your profile that would explain it.

Comment: Okay, on your account I am seeing what you describe.  Do you see the ~800k number when running against my user ID = 149428 as well?  Specifically, I am seeing 799293.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston yeah. I thought I recreated that query somewhere on MSE but only to get a total reach league. That query was using the same formula so that is not going to help.

Comment: Maybe you use this query to figure out which questions shouldn't be in your result: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/358392/how-can-i-sort-my-posts-by-impact-people-reached?UserId=104515 That questin belongs to this MSE answer of mine: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264626/158100

Comment: Yeah, this is interesting.  So the top three question view counts are 312278, 261229, 90844.  799293 - sum([...]) = 134942... close to ~126k.  My answers on those three have < 5 votes and don't meet the other criteria... I think they are false positives.  It may be the final union clause which I don't totally understand, but I'm not super sure.  Do you have any ideas for what to try next?

Comment: I'm happy to look into it but I can't make some reasonable time until Thursday. You might want to write an meta post, asking the question to get some insight in what you see. If no-one answers before Thursday I'll have a look.

Comment: Wow, big difference for me.  The query says 1881411, but I am at 995K

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston - you can try this alternative http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/756276/people-reached?UserId=149428

Comment: Specifically the problem with the original query looks to be the final bit. It will include all answers to questions where the user has a positively scored answer and with rank less than or equal to 3 even if the ranked answer is posted by someone else. There is no check that the user has one in the top 3.

Comment: Do you know how often it gets calculated? Yesterday it was 1.1M, today it's 1.6M. Though, I guess just because I reached 5 upvotes on a major answer, it suddenly got bumped up like that?

Comment: @Honey I guess it is every few hours or so. And it is known to make big jumps (both up and down) if you happen to have answers on highly viewed questions.

Comment: @Honey - You should quite easily spot what happened from here http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/757338/people-reached?UserId=5175709

Comment: Is there an answer date field? I need to report *monthly* impact and can't seem to find any way to group answers by month.

Comment: @DeborahK answer date should be the posts.creationdate as answers are posts with a posttypeid = 2 see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677

Comment: yeah, I've answered a question from 2012 with > +70 and ~200k views and my answer got (re)accepted (not sure if that actually matters) and my "people reached" jumped up by ~200k, although obviously that's not the case

Comment: Would answering my own question with a score of 10 for both question and answer result in double views?

Comment: @Gulzar No, only questions have a viewcount and the query include the applicable questions only once.

Comment: " The view count is only stored for a question, not for each answer. So you can only be 100% sure a question is viewed. For questions with multiple answers you are at a loss." It's worse than this implies, AFAICT; it counts views on the question that happened *chronologically before the answer was posted*. There is no record of viewcount over time.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel not sure how that makes it worse. Anyway: I added that trivia to the answer. If you're interested in more viewcount stuff, see my answer on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292382).

Comment: The details of this answer have been [called into question in another meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429527/208273)

Answer (score 18):

The results from the query in the accepted answer aren't correct.  It will include all questions where the user has a positively scored answer as even though it includes ranking code to calculate the top 3 answers belonging to that question it omits to check that the user has one of those answers...

An alternative SEDE query is here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/757338/people-reached

For user ids [236247](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/757338/people-reached?UserId=236247) and [149428](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/757338/people-reached?UserId=149428) (who both commented on the accepted answer) the results are much closer to what is shown on the site.

NB: Any query using SEDE is going to be vulnerable to the issue of out dated data however. A single vote on a question with a million views can tip the balance between those views being counted or not and this might not exist in the data dump yet.

So this query result includes all candidate questions though only those with "true" in the eligible result column are counted. But seeing the view count for non eligible questions may help with manual investigation of sudden changes.

Comment: Thanks for putting this query together.  It gives much more accurate results for my UID: ~520k currently vs ~526k shown on SO.  I have a feeling you're right that the difference between these numbers is probably just data lag — it looks like the SEDE data may lag by a week or so.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston - It looks like the data dump was updated since I posted this. There is still a 3K discrepancy though so there is presumably something slightly different between my query and the one used in production.