# How does "nk people reached" work on stackexchange sites?

Tags: support

How does "Nunber k people reached" work on stackexchange sites?

I have seen "number k people reached" column  increasing and decreasing on my stackoverflow profile. 
I recently deleted an answer from my spanish exchange account and it decreased to 2k from 3k.

How does it work?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251661/what-happened-to-the-other-people-my-impact-people-reached-just-dropped

Comment: To answer your title question: "Rather poorly."

Comment: _This question has been asked before and already has an answer_. Not really: It's been [asked before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-the-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated), but it doesn't have an answer.