# Revise user profile "Impact" panel to mention number of countries reached

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, tag-wiki

There's an "Impact" panel in the upper right corner of the SO user profile page. It says how many people a user has reached.  May I suggest you revise it from, e.g. "1.7M people reached" to, e.g.  "1.7M people in 56 countries reached" ?

I guess you'd gather this information from geolocating visitor IP addresses.

Maybe similar information could be included on tag pages, or even on the hover panels for tags.  A tag could say : "upvoted answers contributed by nnn users from mm countries." or some such thing.

This is a simple way to remind us that our work as developers touches people everywhere.  It's something that a platform like Stack Exchange can do.

I offer this after reading Mr. Spolsky's post [Time to take a stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand)

Comment: What would the performance implications be? The current implementation is heavily denormalized; it folds all views into a simple incrementing counter (one per question) after the fifteen-minute deduplication interval. Maybe this could have 200+ buckets, one per country, but that's not exactly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The spirit of this was noble, but even now, the number of people reached is still contentious and dependent on [loosely related and easily gamed data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320520/1079354), such as view count of a question.

There's also the matter of people fabricating their geolocation.  Since it's self-reported, it could be "Milky Way Galaxy, Orion Arm" for all we know, and then that might get counted as a country if one were to do this the lazy way.

Ultimately, I'm not sure I see the benefit to including that stat in the profile.  Given how it can be gamified, I'm not sure I want it around at all, honestly...

Comment: It's "self-reported" only for registered users. Most views come from anonymous visitors without any profile, for whom the IP can be tracked back to location. While not 100% reliable, I'd say at least 95% of those are correct, at least for taking the country. (So the request is totally feasible.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Would not say "totally", considering that SE found it infeasible even to exclude the question views that predate user's answer to that question.

Comment: @zaq different thing. Time of view is not being stored, but it should be simple enough to locate country upon a view, and raise a counter.