# Why did my impact count decrease?

Tags: discussion, support, people-reached

My people impact was around 80k+ till yesterday but today it got down to 3K, I want to know why it got reduced to 3k. Also, I want to understand the full mechanism behind this process.

**Edit:-**
After reading the duplicate marked linked I understood the logic behind the impact calculation, in that question, there was a [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1?UserId=811) to see the impact post wise I saw that my highest ranked post wasn't deleted then why did it reduce?

Comment: @Ivar There's no rep on meta, so answering questions about a specific case, even if they have been marked as a dupe, is not as frowned upon here as it is on main (especially on questions tagged [meta-tag:support]). Imo you've done good answering it, even if it's a dupe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/358392/how-can-i-sort-my-posts-by-impact-people-reached?UserId=6947385), you can see that 78k of your 80k came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20857773/479156). Reading [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290491/479156), your answer is *not* the accepted answer, does *not* have a score of at least 5 and does *not* have at least 20% of the vote count. It **was** in the top 3 answers, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34709722/479156) got an up vote yesterday, kicking you out of the top 3.