# On Stack Overflow, "IMPACT ... people reached"

Tags: discussion, profile-page, people-reached

In my account there is an area called **IMPACT**. Earlier it has showed *116k reached*, but after I have got 2000 reputation points, it has now changed to

> IMPACT ~65k people reached

Why does this happen? Is it some AI task or reaching a limit?

Comment: What do you mean by reaching limit?

Comment: in profile `https://stackoverflow.com/users/6183113/chanaka-weerasinghe` earlier reached 113K

Comment: Same happend to you [as to this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369574/why-did-my-impact-count-decrease). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56849732/479156) was in the top 3 answers, but yesterday [another answer got two upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56849484/timeline), kicking you out of the top 3.

Comment: @Ivar wow, what a difference one answer makes.