# Get "people reached" value from Stack Overflow API

Tags: support, profile-page, api, people-reached

Is there a way to obtain the `people reached` value from the stack overflow API?

I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated) about how this value is calculated, and how to play with some queries in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1?UserId=811). However, I'm not sure how to use this queries to obtain the value from Stack Overflow and use it on my own web app.

Comment: That attribute isn't available in the API.

Comment: [Add the 'people reached' count to the API?](https://stackapps.com/q/6301)

Comment: There is a 2.3 version of the Stack API but it doesn't look like it is in there either or it is not in the default filter.

Comment: Thanks @rene. I think that with SEDE queries I can get what I want. The queries have a link `Download CSV`, but how to get the results in JSON format?

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez SEDE doesn't have public endpoints that return JSON. It used to have OData endpoints  but those were broken in [2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230748/odata-feeds-are-down) and have not been re-enabled leading to removing those in [2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254120/158100)