# How often is the 'People Reached' counter updated?

Tags: discussion, people-reached

I have the habit of checking my own profile every now and then just to see how it looks.

By the beginning of this week, I had "reached" roughly 6 thousand people. Today, I checked it again and this number jumped to 96 thousand! Looks like these 90k came out of the blue as I did not participate in StackOverflow too much this week.

I have answered only one very popular question (which is a recent answer to an old question) and my answers do not have many upvotes (the top one only has 5 upvotes), so I am not really sure how this happened.

Three(±) weeks ago I had checked this number and it was in 5K, so this jump of 90 thousand people, at least as per my investigation, happened this week.

As I don't believe I reached this many people in only a week, I would like to know whether these numbers are updated randomly(i.e it can sometimes be updated daily and sometimes monthly, etc) or if there's a newly introduced bug with the counter that made my "People reached" go sky high.

Comment: Looks like it was your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681213/what-is-the-difference-between-amazon-sns-and-amazon-sqs/55261792#55261792) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681213/what-is-the-difference-between-amazon-sns-and-amazon-sqs) that shot you up there. The post has 89k views. Of course that doesn't mean they all viewed your answer as it is an older question that you just posted a recent answer to, but apparently that's just how the "People Reached" number get calculated--any answer you post just inherits all the views from that post.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @n8te. This is interesting but still weird. That question in particular has 89K views overall. When I posted my answer, it already was a popular question, so I would say after my answer, this question must not have got more than 10K views (if that much), which would only add 10K to my "people reached" number. If the way it's calculated is simply by blindly inheriting the number of views in a given question, then I think these numbers are completely erroneous.

Comment: I'm sort of speculating since I don't know the exact way it is calculated but it does seem that way from what I've observed before. Maybe someone will come along and correct me but that either has to be the way it's calculated based on the situation you described, or it really is a bug.

Comment: It was posting an answer to that popular question that did it. People reached makes no sense as a statistic. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290491/6083675

Comment: "Score at least 5 OR", that's what did it! My answer reached the score of 5 today and immediately inherited the total views for that given question! Thanks, @Laurel