# Why does "people reached" use the full amount of views for late answers?

Tags: discussion

My profile section on Stack Overflow says I impacted 2.2m people. Great, I love it, happy to help etc etc.

However, this just incorrect, it used to be 500k~ for the past year or so, and only recently increased to 2.2m. This happened because I [received my fifth upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated) on a late answer to a very popular question (with a 2019 update).

Instead of counting the views *since then*, it takes the entire view count of that question and adds it to my question, while I do not complain about  it, it feels somewhat wrong, or incorrect that I'm being credited with impacting so many people, especially when the *actual* number lies considerably lower.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"People reached" is a (extremely) rough estimate.

There is no information stored about the view count on a question when you're first active on it, nor  is there any "clever" system in place to only count a percentage of the views based on what percentage of the question's lifetime you had a stake in it.

Basically, "People reached" is a naïve sum of page view counters.

Anything more clever than that would probably be a significant server load for too little gain.

Comment: Assumed so, but couldn't find any related questions on SO/SE regarding this. At least when someone looks into it they can find a proper explanation of how the system works. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Although I did just find a comment on an answer on MSE saying "Sanity Check: So I post the 73th answer to a question with a million views. A year later it gets to 5 votes. Does that mean I helped 1 million people?" which seems to address the issue, although nothing has happened with it since then.

Comment: @Roberrrt I asked pretty much the same question last week: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384847/how-often-is-the-people-reached-counter-updated

Comment: @ThalesMinussi Another pretty significant indicator that SO's search functionality isn't doing what it should do here.