# How do I fix the missing impact value on Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, people-reached

I have noticed that the user profile does not include the impact value on private teams (Stack Overflow for Teams):

[image: Missing impact value on Stack Overflow for Teams]

Since the label is there, I think the value is missing and this is exactly by design.

How do I fix the missing impact value on Stack Overflow for Teams?

P.S. I assume that [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated) and [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/757338/people-reached) can be used for doing the computation myself after syncing the private team data.

Comment: Teams profile update is in progress. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319375/help-us-improve-the-user-profile-and-settings