# Does bounty increase my 'people reached'?

Tags: support, people-reached

Does it affect my 'people reached' on my activity page if I start a bounty of someone's question?

[image: Screenshot showing part of a user's "Activity" section, "Impact" box (to the right) - the approximate number of "people reached"]

I ask this because I just started a bounty on a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022696/how-to-change-browse-button-to-look-like-modern-dragdrop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I start a bounty of *someone's question*?

Putting a bounty itself does *not* affect the "people reached" stats. The stats only count your *own* posts while also fulfilling some other criteria mentioned on [What does "people reached" signify and how is it calculated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290491/2821954):

> - **Questions**
>
>   - Non-deleted only
> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

If it is on your own question, then the bounty might increase the "people reached" stats *indirectly* from future visitors' view who are interested/curious about the question.