# "People reached" counts accepted answers regardless of their score

Tags: support, people-reached

There is a description of how "people reached" statistics are calculated, here on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320520/21350362), and also on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534). For user’s answers, it is supposed to be views of the parent question if the answer:

> - Non-deleted AND
> - Score > 0 AND
> - Not self-answers AND
> - Also meeting one or more of the following criteria:
>
>   - In the top 3 answers OR
>   - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>   - Score at least 5 OR
>   - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

This logic was also implemented in [People Reached #1](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/756276) and [People Reached #2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/757338) SEDE queries.

This can be interpreted as: if the answer has zero or negative score, then it **shouldn’t be accounted for** regardless of the acceptance.

However, while inspecting users with reputation 12, 14 (possibly an accepted answer with negative score) and 16 (zero score) it can be seen that the impact **actually includes the views** of answered questions regardless of their score. Examples at the time of writing: [956959](https://stackoverflow.com/users/956959), [333568](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333568), [51828](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51828).

Condition `Score > 0 OR is the Accepted Answer` is mentioned as a proposition in one of the [trailing answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275905). And also, [public prototype #1](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267) SEDE query implements that logic.

So is it a bug or not-that-well-documented feature?